# Facing issue while handling if controller

Tags: jmeter

I am facing issue while using if controller in my jmeter script.

i used condition `"${Response}"=="Test unsuccessful"` in if controller.
Response variable contains complete response and i'm checking test unsuccessful in response if not it should execute next. however its not executing next even though we are not getting correct response.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the condition like `"${Response}"=="Test unsuccessful"`, you can use a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) if it resolves to `true` (or `false`), however if you want to compare 2 strings and basing on result conditionally execute (or don't execute child sampler(s)) you need to use a function which compares the strings and returns `true` or `false`, i.e. [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) would be a good candidate:

```
${__jexl3("${Response}"=="Test unsuccessful",)}
```

More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage)

[image]